# How to call a function for certain value matches with previous

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>User Id:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.userId">
</div>
        <label>Items:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.item">
       <label>Quantity:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.quantity">
       <label>Card:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.card">
       <label>Other:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a.other">

      <button type="button" ng-click="addData(a.userId)">Add</button>
```

Directive Code:-

```
  scope.addData = function (userId) {
   var prev = userId;
      if(prev == userId){
         scope.list=[];       
         scope.list.push(scope.a);
      }
    };
```

I have some data which I am pushing in an array, I want to push the data for same `userId` from previous. If user changes the `userId` then it wont push the data. I am trying to check the previous value but this logic doesnt work. Anyone can suggest some different logic.

Comment: Form where can we get previous userId?

Comment: Could explain a bit more what you want to achieve? Also explain how your data in the array is structured

Comment: I guess you just need to store `userId` in `scope.userId` on your `scope.addData()`

Comment: What about data before previous? For example the following ids sequence: 1 then 2 then 1. Don't you need to check all ids to be unique within the list?